C# WPF. Window on top of all windows Windows 11
I have a fullscreen application that does not capture the cursor context, but should always be displayed on top of any windows, including Windows context windows, the taskbar, a pinned task manager.
Here's what I have at the moment:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private const int EXIT_HOTKEY_ID = 9355;
        private const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
        private const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        private const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
        private const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
        private const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        private const uint SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        private const uint SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010;
        private const uint SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
        private const int WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4;
    
        private DispatcherTimer _timer;
        private IntPtr _hwnd;
        private IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        private HookProc _proc;
    
        private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam);
    
        private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
    
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
            Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
    
            ShowActivated = true;
            Topmost = true;
        }
    
        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            int exStyle = GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
            SetWindowPos(_hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    
            _timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)
            };
            _timer.Tick += TimerTick;
            _timer.Start();
    
            _proc = new HookProc(HookCallback);
            _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    
            AttachToForegroundWindow();
        }
    
        private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
            DetachFromForegroundWindow();
        }
    
        private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetWindowPos(_hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        }
    
        private IntPtr SetHook(HookProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }
    
        private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                // Checking whether a window needs to be forced to the foreground
                SetWindowPos(_hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    
        private void AttachToForegroundWindow()
        {
            IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
            if (foregroundWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                uint foregroundThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, out _);
                uint currentThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(_hwnd, out _);
    
                if (foregroundThreadId != currentThreadId)
                {
                    AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, foregroundThreadId, true);
                    BringWindowToTop(_hwnd);
                    AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, foregroundThreadId, false);
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void DetachFromForegroundWindow()
        {
            IntPtr foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
            if (foregroundWindow != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                uint foregroundThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, out _);
                uint currentThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(_hwnd, out _);
    
                if (foregroundThreadId != currentThreadId)
                {
                    AttachThreadInput(currentThreadId, foregroundThreadId, false);
                }
            }
        }
    
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    
        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool BringWindowToTop(IntPtr hWnd);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);
    
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);    
    }

My window appears on top of any program windows except for standard Windows 11 context or pop-up windows and Task Manager, which is pinned on top of windows.
The only way I found to partially fix this is to set not only SetWindowPos but also SetWindowLong by timer, but in this case the context or pop-up window of Windows 11 closes. And it does not work with Task Manager at all.
Maybe you know a way? A solution of any complexity level will do.
Additionally. My app only has one window, which is mostly transparent. This window only shows the widgets I need, like my screen keyboard.

You can't create an always-on-top window. Imagine what would happen if two instances of your program run at the same time.

The second instance of the program won't run, I've taken that into account. And I've seen programs that do what I need, but their source code is unavailable and they're not in C#.

And I should clarify. I don't need all the window functions to run on top, just the render. But I do need my window to not steal the control context. So I can't imitate it (with a screenshot or anything).
